# Efficient way to elevate signal over time if it drops significantly over time

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, data-transformation

I am wondering what would be the most efficient way to correct signal if it drops out significantly in some period of time. Like in the figure green signal dropped out between around 16:26 and 19:16 and I would like to elevate it to the same level like before 16:26 and after 19:16 using statistics.

[image: Please check the figure here]

One of the idea is to check mean of each portion of data and if it variates significantly from previous mean and standard deviation to treat that portion like missing values and use some method such as expectation-maximization to approximate the data from that portion or period of time.

Thanks!